# Exceptions on Firestore listeners

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I experienced issues with Firebase Firestore (17.0.1) from time to time (on June 16, July 3 & 4, July 11, July 15, July 18).

[Exception: com.google.firebase.firestore.i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AKjx.png)

For a short period of time, I monitor many FirebaseFirestoreException on a Firebase listener : PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions, 
INTERNAL: An internal error occurred or DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: The datastore operation timed out, or the data was unavailable.

Here is my listener :

```
CollectionReference scanLogRef = db.collection("users/" + user.getUid() + "/scanlog");

Query scanLogQuery = scanLogRef
    .orderBy("created", com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .whereGreaterThan("created", thirtyDaysBefore);

scanRegistration = scanLogQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        if (e != null) {
            FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception(TAG+" / scanRegistration / "+e));
            return;
        }
...
```

I don't understand the exceptions : the users are identified (ID available) and it works perfectly well outside these periods.

What could be the root cause of theses Firestore exceptions ?